# Jackson serialization key and value from one object

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to create a custom serializer to generate Pair object but I want to avoid "key" and "value" fields when the object is serialized.

Object pojo:

```
public class TypeObjectPair implements Serializable {


    private final String canonicalObjectName;
    private final Object object;


    public String getKey() {
        return canonicalObjectName;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return object;
    }


}
```

Person class. (Theoretically could be any other object class)

```
class Person{
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

Final object to serialize:

```
TypeObjectPair obj = new TypeObjectPair("com.example.Person", new Person(1, "Peter"));
```

Required output:

```
{
    "com.example.object" : {
                              "id" : 1,
                              "name" : "Peter"    
                           }
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: What about doing a simple google search? http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: @jbx, I was googling it but no results, even link that you have sent does not demonstrate how to achieve that.

Comment: @WildGoat Then your question is not that clear what you want to achieve. You mention a `Pair`, which means your object just has one key and one value, but your required output shows an object with multiple keys and values. How you are imagining this to magically fit in your pair is not really clear.

Comment: @jbx, it could be any object inside. For example Person. See updated answer

Comment: @WildGoat Then why aren't you simply annotating the fields of `Person` with the right JSON property keys? So `@JsonProperty("id") int id; @JsonProperty("name") String name;`

Comment: @jbx, how does that would help? Having one object I want nested structure. For example, id is a key for the person but not having that information next to each other. Please see my output example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Map<K, V>` with [`@JsonAnyGetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html):

```java
public class TypeObjectPair {

    private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

    public TypeObjectPair(String key, Object value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then use as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeObjectPair pair = new TypeObjectPair("com.example.object", new Person(1, "Peter"));
String json = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(pair);
```

The output will be:

```json
{
  "com.example.object" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Peter"
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of jackson gives you this output? Because for me it still outputs "value" and "key" while serialiazing a map. Any ideas how to avoid that?

Comment: @WildGoat I'm using Jackson 2.9 and tested with the code posted in the answer. I don't use any getters besides `getData()`. If you have other getters, annotated them with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I have just forgot to remove getters.